# Polling a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

In a Google Apps Script web app (`doGet()`), I want to refresh display once a certain spreadsheet changes. I was thinking about polling the spreadsheet every ten seconds or so. However, there seems to be no timer, only an [ugly workaround](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/2pqhh_eTIvQ) (though, smart it is).

Any idea how to realize an automatic refresh?

Comment: Related [How do I make a Sidebar display values from cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30628894/1595451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [HtmlServices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) to build your app, then you'll have javascript regular `setTimeout` function where you can configure your timer easily. On UiApp though, I think you're restricted to the very smart workaround you linked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use HtmlServices! I didn't think about that, and I believe it is an option for the app in question.